# (UK) Law Report Style Letters Along Margin

Tags: margins

UK law reports, as seen in the page below from the Weekly Law Reports, traditionally have at each page's inside margin, in regularly spaced intervals, a column of letters.  This makes for easier citation.  Is it possible to replicate this column of letters in LaTeX? 
[image: law report excerpt]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think it can be done simply with the `eso-pic` package and the `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` command.

Comment: How about `\marginpar`?

Comment: The `lineno` package could work. You can change the counter to be upper case alphabetical, and tell it to number only every X lines. https://texblog.org/2012/02/08/adding-line-numbers-to-documents/

Comment: If you don't necessarily need the letters to line up with the lines, but want them to be absolutely positioned on the page, maybe you can use the [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos?lang=en) package.

Comment: I agree with @WillieWong second suggestion. It seems that the letters are set in a certain distance from the top margin, independent of line number. I is just to stack the right number of textpos textbox, and add it to the running header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an MWE using [textpos](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos). I have defined a command, `Leftblock`, which I added to the running headers. Then, you have the marginal letters on every page. I had to embrace the font commands inside an extra group `{}`, because the formatting ‘bleeded’ to the other text in the top header. The documentclass [scrartcl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) from [KOMAscript](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) is for convenience; it is easy to change the running headers, fonts, margins *etc*.

As @WillyWong suggests, as an alternative to put `\Leftblock`-command in the running header, you may load the package [everypage](https://ctan.org/pkg/everypage) and in the preamble use the following command:

```
\AddEverypageHook{\Leftblock}
```

The distance between the marginal letters are set arbitrarily. You may chose another grid that gives a different distance. For example:

```
\TPGrid[20mm,31mm]{100}{100}
```

and use 0,12,24,36 etc. in the definition of the textblocks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=10, fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\lohead{\Leftblock [2018] 2 WLR}
\rohead{\thepage\par MWB Business Exchange Ltd v Rock Advertising Ltd (SC(E))}
\cofoot{\textcopyright 2018 The Incorporeated Concil of Law Reporting for England and Wales}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\TPGrid[15mm,30mm]{8}{8}                        % Divide page in 8x8 grid 


\setcounter{page}{1603}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\small\color{darkgray}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Leftblock}{{\normalfont\sffamily\itshape%
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,0)A\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,1)B\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,2)C\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,3)D\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,4)E\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,5)F\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,6)G\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{10}(0,7)H\end{textblock}
}}


\begin{document}
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
\begin{centering}
Supreme Court

\bigskip

{\bfseries\large MWB Business Exchange Centres Ltd v Rock Advertising Ltd}

\end{centering}

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}ll>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
2018 & Feb 1; & Baroness Hale of Richmond PSC, Lord Wilson,\\
&May 16&    Lord Sumption, Lord Lloyd-Jones, Lord Briggs JJSC\\
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{centering}

{\bfseries\large (2018] UKSC 24}

\end{centering}

\smallskip

\begin{description}
\itshape\item Contract  --- Formation  --- Variation  --- Clause  in  licence  agreement  expressly precluding  oral 
modification of  agreement --- Parties later orally agreeing tovary fee  pa yment schedule set out in 
licence agreement --- Whether variation valid --- Whether ``nooral modification'' clauses legally effective
\end{description}

\smallskip

The defendant company entered into a contract, by way of a licence agreement to occupy premises 
managed by the claimant company, with a ``no oral modification'' clause inserted in clause 7.6 of the 
agreement stipulating that ``all variations to this licence must be agreed, set out in writing and 
signed on behalf of both parties before they take effect''. When the defendant fell into arrears of 
licence payments, its sole director, during a telephone conversation with one of the claimant's 
employees, proposed a revised payment schedule so that the early payments were reduced and the 
difference loaded onto the later payments. Having understood the employee to have agreed to the 
variation, he made what he considered to be the first payment under the purported revised 
agreement. The employee's manager, however, did not agree to any variation of the licence 
agreement, locked out the defendant and issued proceedings for payment of the balance of arrears. 
The defendant counterclaimed for damages for wrongful exclusion from the premises, in reliance on 
the oral agreement and payment thereunder. The judge held that the employee had ostensible 
authority to agree to a variation of the terms of the licence, that she had in fact done so, and 
that the commercial benefit of securing the sums due under the contract which the new arrangement 
held out was sufficient consideration for the agreement to vary, but that the amendment to the 
contract had not been effective because it was not in writing as required by clause 7.6 and so the 
claimant had been entitled to proceed against the defendant for non-payment in accordance with the 
original written agreement. The judge also rejected an argument that the claimant was estopped from 
disavowing the variation by having accepted the payment made after the oral agreement, holding that 
the payment had not amounted to a detriment to the defendant when it was in any event in arrears to 
a larger amount. The Court of Appeal allowed the defendant's appeal, holding that the principle of 
freedom of contract entitled parties to agree to depart from a previously-agreed ``no oral 
modification" clause and clause 7.6 therefore did not preclude an application of the revised 
agreement, and remitted the claims to the County Court for determination on that basis.

On the claimant's appeal---

\emph{Held}, (1) (Lord Briggs JSC dissenting) that although at common law there were no formal 
requirements for the validity of a simple contract, which could be made orally or in writing, there 
was no principled reason why parties could not agree to bind themselves to a provision laying down 
specified conditions for any subsequent variation of their contract; that, in particular, ``no oral 
modification'' clauses, which were in common use because they served a legitimate business purpose 
and were intended to achieve contractual certainty about the terms agreed, did not cause any 
mischief or conflict with any overriding public policy; that the law of contract did not normally 
obstruct the legitimate purposes of businessmen in such circumstances; that there was no conceptual 
inconsistency between a general rule allowing a contract to be made informally and a specific rule 
that effect would be given to a contract which required  writing  for  a  variation;  that  unjust  
reliance  on  a  ``no oral modification

\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive effort! P.S. I had to change `\rohead{\thepage\par` to `\rohead{\thepage\\ ' to stop a Runaway argument? error under xelatex.

Comment: @Cicada I use `pdftex` and had no problem. When you have complicated headers, you may also try using a tabular.

Comment: Instead of squeezing the the `\Leftblock` command into the running header, maybe it would make sense to run it using [everypage](https://ctan.org/pkg/everypage?lang=en)?

Comment: @WillieWong I have updated my answer with a reference to the package.